# getting aapt error in android while running the program

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, aapt

I am getting this error message frequently

I installed all components perfectly

[image: error]

Comment: re-check the path of the android sdk which you are giving to eclipse.

Comment: Well.... did u check if aapt is present in that location?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem some couple of days back. Not sure if this solution will work for you too, but you could give it a try, if the symptoms are the same.

```
1. I have an antivirus that moved aapt.exe to the quarantine. 
   Hence check the settings of the antivirus if you have one, 
   and place the folder that contains aapt.exe 
   (that means all the versions) into the exclusion folder.

2. Once that is done, If the antivirus complains that aapt wants to modify 
things and it may harm the system, select watch if you have 
such an option (or basically allow, and keep under watch).

3. And build the project again.
```

Hope that helps and works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

**1)Check your xml or check anything writes wrong**

**2)Clean your project**

**3)Otherwise close the eclipse and start it again**

I also occurred same problem and it would be my style.xml file so i change this with proper syntex and it get resolve after restarting my eclipse.

Hope this helps you.